# Why does my element keep getting smaller after a mouseleave effect?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseleave

I am new to jQuery (and web dev in itself) and trying to get an image to expand when I mouse-over it, and return to it's original size when I remove the mouse-over. However I don't know why my element keeps getting smaller and smaller if I hover on and off it several times. How do I prevent this from happening?

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/m74262yb/)

Thank you in advance!

**The #testDiv is a circle.

```js
 jQuery (function( $ ) {
   $('#testDiv').on('mouseenter',function() {
        $(this).animate({  
          height: "+=20px",
          width: "+=20px",
          borderRadius: "+=10px",

        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
          $(this).animate({
          height: "-=20px",
          width: "-=20px",
          borderRadius: "-=10px",

          });
        });
     });
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
it seems that you trigger the mouseleave event multiple times and the properties are reduces multiple times see console https://jsfiddle.net/m74262yb/2/

```js
 jQuery (function( $ ) {
   $('#testDiv').on('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).animate({  
      height: "120px",
      width: "120px",
      borderRadius: "40px",

    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).animate({
      height: "100px",
      width: "100px",
      borderRadius: "50px",

      });
    });
 });
 } );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m74262yb/1/

you can try css transitions:

css:

```
#testDiv{
    transition:all 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
#testDiv:hover {

  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m74262yb/3/

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was pretty obvious to just use fixed sizes. One more note however, is that if you hover on and off multiple times in a relatively fast manner, the code falls behind and stops working properly even if you slow down again. Is there a way we can optimize this for performance?

Comment: maybe, do your users have hover fast and multiple times on that object?

Comment: i think you may have better luck with css animations/transition